# Can a transpiler replace polyfills?

Tags: javascript

Here's my understanding of a polyfill vs transpiler: both polyfills and transpilers allow you to use features that may not be natively available in the browser but achieve it via different means. Polyfills achieve the result by defining an API if it doesn't exist. Transpilers convert your code so it's supported by more browsers (e.g. ES6 to ES5 syntax).

So if polyfills and transpilers are different ways of achieving the same result could a transpiler be used instead of a polyfill? If so what's the advantage of using a polyfill?

Comment: Imo this is a good question. But the advantage of using a polyfill is that your source code is using the latest standard code (and is just polyfilled). Once the polyfill is no longer needed, you simply remove the polyfill from your source code, rather than refactoring all of your source code. The advantages are seen long term.

Comment: @EdmundReed: Wouldn't the transpiler have the same effect? You write your source code using the latest and greatest language version and the build process converts it to whatever the target environment needs.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right actually, think I just had a brain fart. I can't think of a benefit to using a polyfill over a transpiler in this case.

Comment: Most transpilers actually include polyfills under the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So if polyfills and transpilers are different ways of achieving the same result

That's not quite right. Polyfills cannot be used to support new syntax features, only APIs. And not even always those (for example `Proxy`s).

> ... could a transpiler be used instead of a polyfill?

For the time being at least, transpiler are not knowledgeable enough to be able to polyfill APIs. Take the following code for example:

```
function doWork(items) {
    return items.find(x => x.name === 'foo');
}
```

Now, what is `.find` here? Is it [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) that needs to be polyfilled? Or is `items` some other user defined object that happens to have a `.find` method?

This would be possible with type information, so this would be able to work for typescript, but it wouldn't work for plain JavaScript.

Having said that, even if you *could* transpile them, it doesn't necessarily make sense. Including a polyfill is a much simpler solution than replacing an API with an equivalent piece of code. Just look at the [polyfill of `Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill): It's much easier to include this piece of code once at the beginning (which the transpiler could do for you of course) than to replace *every* callsite of `Array.from` with that.

However, if you simply mean whether a transpiler could replace `Array.from(x)` calls with calls to `array_from(x)` where `array_from` contains the polyfill code, then yes, absolutely. This is something than Babel can do for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are few situations that transpiler won't work.

For example, `eval()` takes a string and runs it as a piece of code. Consider an old browser without some transpilable and polyfillable new-gen API (say, `someNewAPI`), you won't be able to directly `eval` that (you must runtime-transpile that first) if you are using transpiler but it works with polyfills.

To be honest, this situation is very rare, most time you can just replace polyfills.

---

Anyway many APIs are easier to polyfill than to transpile. For example, `fetch` is just an easy piece of code as polyfill (actually, most browsers are just using JavaScript instead of native code to implement `fetch` (type `fetch` in your browser console and you can see that it is not `[native code]`)). But transpiling `fetch` to `XMLHttpRequest` and so on will be a disaster.